# hash table topicData object in javascript to match the topic with the text

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am facing a performance problem in my following code because the number of topic I have to match with the text in gmail messages is more than 1000 because of which it either crashes my gmail or slow down. I am thinking of using hash table but I am unsure on how to use it properly and how do i check with the `node.textContent`. Here is what I have done and it is without hash table.

```
var topicData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Courses'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'miss'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'out'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'your'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'savings'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: 'and'
    }
];

function fetchTopics() {
    // const apiUrl = `http://localhost:3020/v2/emails`;
    // const headers = new Headers();
    // headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return topicData.map(datum => {
        return searchPage(datum.name);
    });
    // fetch(apiUrl, {
    //  method: 'GET',
    //  headers
    // })
    //  .then(function(response) {
    //      return response.json();
    //  })
    //  .then(function(data) {
    //      topicData.map(datum => searchPage(data.name));
    //  })
    //  .catch(function(err) {
    //      console.log('err', err);
    //  });
}

/*  the searchPage function takes an argument which is going
to set the variable re. Then iterate through topic array and call the searchPage function
for each value inside it while passing that value to the function
*/
function searchPage(topic) {
    console.log('topic', topic);
    var re = new RegExp(topic, 'g'); // example regex that the function will use for search
    var regs;

    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        document.body,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        function(node) {
            if ((regs = re.exec(node.textContent))) {
                if (!node.parentNode.classList.contains('highlighted_text')) {
                    var match = document.createElement('A');
                    match.appendChild(document.createTextNode(regs[0]));
                    match.href = `https://app.com/CustomTopic/${
                        regs[0]
                    }`;
                    match.classList.add('highlighted_text');

                    var after = node.splitText(regs.index);
                    after.nodeValue = after.nodeValue.substring(regs[0].length);
                    node.parentNode.insertBefore(match, after);
                }
            }
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
        },
        false
    );

    walker.nextNode();
}

// Run when the whole document loads
$(window).bind('load', function() {
    document.addEventListener('click', init);
    fetchTopics();
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    fetchTopics();
});
```